# Can I repair Windows 10 v1909 system files with a v2004 ISO?

Tags: windows-10, filesystem-corruption, dism, sfc, windows-system-image

I have a laptop running Windows 10 v1909 with system file corruption that `DISM` and `SFC` are not able to repair. Can I repair it with a v2004 ISO image, without upgrading to the newer version?

Comment: @JW0914 I have used both the ISM tools you mentioned but none of them worked.

Comment: @JW0914 What if I go back to previous version of Windows 10 after upgrading to versions 2004, will it affect my system files or keep my system files uncorrupted ?

Comment: @John What if I go back to previous version of Windows 10 after upgrading to versions 2004, will it affect my system files or keep my system files uncorrupted ?

Comment: Though Microsoft no longer has v. 1909 available, there are othr sources, e.g. https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/where-can-i-download-windows-10-version-1909/ae2c79a3-6022-4d1f-9c61-abd07d1132cd .*Caveat* It's hard to be sure the ISO is trustworthy. Rufus is likely OK: https://pureinfotech.com/download-windows-10-1909-iso-after-2004-releases/